# Which MVVM frameworks help develop an application easier and faster?

Tags: wpf, prism, mvvm-light, mvvm-toolkit

I know there are some MVVM frameworks, such as MVVM Toolkit, MVVM Light, and Prism.

I was wondering  with which one of those MVVM frameworks is it easier and faster to develop an application?

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this as it's a subjective question. This really belong on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but i prefer the mvvm-light. Its very lightweight and easy to use.
You should watch the creator's two videos from mix: [video1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/EX14) [video2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03).

Comment: +1 for mvvm light. It's my choice because of its simplicity... it targets only the mvvm plumbing, and does not try to encapsulate the whole application design.

Comment: Yeah, and its doesnt force you anything. I like Bugnion's motto too: the mvvm is just a pattern, everything else are helpers. And the mvvm light are really these helpers.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [**WAF**](http://waf.codeplex.com/) it is an opensource framework for generating MVVM.

It is really easy to use

Answer (score 1):

Easier and faster is relative.  From my experience though you can't go wrong with [Caliburn](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) Micro or Mvvm Light.  Caliburn Micro's screens and conductors, among others, are a very nice feature.